# jquery stopped working wp_enqueue_script

Tags: jquery, wordpress

In my wp theme I had jquery and various scripts referenced directly in head. And everything worked perfectly.

Later I changed it to wordpress way of including scripts thus going to functions.php and registering all js from there.

After removing duplicate js from head nothing works!

Any ideas? I've a feeling it is related to noconflict mode of wp, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Have a crack at [this](http://digwp.com/2009/06/including-jquery-in-wordpress-the-right-way/) and [this](http://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/).

Comment: @Adnan still does not work :(

Comment: @Sandro Dzneladze have you check it with firebug or something?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referencing your own jQuery I find that wordpress inherently has conflict issues (for me at least). So I usually remove the wordpress inclusion of jQuery (in the functions.php file) and add my own dynamic ref in the header.php - try that, it usually fixes all of my wordpress jQuery qualms.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery version that ships with WordPress does indeed call noConflict(). If you load jQuery from Google's servers instead, you will get a version without the noConflict hassle.

You could still let WordPress handle the actual inclusion of the script, though, for example with something like this in functions.php:

```
function fix_noconflict() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery' , 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts' , 'fix_noconflict' );
```